# SharePoint 2007 Automatic Workflows

Tags: 2007, workflow

Is there a way to create a workflow that will check an entire list.  I want to create a workflow that will check all of the entries in a list for a particular item.  I do not want to have to fire the workflow for each particular list item.  I would like the workflow to automatically go through all of the entries within the list automatically.  Can this be done within the workflow?

Comment: I think for this would be better to create timer job.

Answer (score 0):

In SP2007 - Stock workflows (ones done out of the box or custom workflows designed in SP Designer 2007) can only be fired manually, when a new item is created, or when a item is modified, or all of the above. Key point being not programmatically and assigned to a specific item (the one being created or modified).

However, you can build one that would pause for say, 24 hours, run then finish. Then have another workflow modify some field in the list, which would cause Workflow #1 to run again. But again - key caveat - it will only apply to one specific item.